# Is there a way to add fields to an already generated Scaffold in Rails (migration, controller changes, view changes)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already generated a scaffold in Rails.

Now, a bit later, I want to add a new field to the scaffold.

How to do that easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of scaffolds is to get you up and running quickly, but once you start editing the files you probably don't want to be re-scaffolding things.

That said, adding new fields is usually a 3 step process, add the field to the database, add the field to the form, add the field to the permitted list of fields in the controller. Here's what this looks like:

**Add the field to the database**
From the terminal, type in `rails generate migration AddNAMEToMODELS NAME:TYPE`. This will add a field named `NAME` to the `MODELS` model and its type with be `TYPE`. This will create the migration file in db/migrations/TIMESTAMP_AddNAMEToMODEL.rb. A real example of this would be `rails generate migration AddBirthdateToUsers birthday:date`

**Add the field to the form**
To be able to edit the new field, you will want to add it the the form, which is located at `app/views/MODELS/_form.html.erb`. The default format for this new field would be:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.FIELD_TYPE :name %>
</div>
```

**Add field to permitted list in controller**
Strong Parameters is a feature that ensures user cannot submit arbitrary data. It allows you to have a white list of permitted fields. This is usually done in a MODEL_params method in you controller. All you need to do in most cases is add the field to the list:

Before:

```
def category_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email)
end
```

After:

```
def category_params
  params.require(: user).permit(:email, :name)
end
```

Comment: What would be the easiest way to write a generator to automate these 3 steps? Is the thing to write generators still called Thor?